# Check comments in each PHP line

Tags: php, parsing, comments

I need a tool which should check if comments are written before each php line. I tested a tool PHPLOC. But this is telling me total commented lines. What i need to check if comments are written before every line or not. How can I do this? Is there any tool available ?

Comment: Perhaps [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) returns comment blocks too?

Comment: You might do best with making a simple script to verify this (in awk, ruby, etc) rather than looking for an existing tool.

Comment: existing tool saves time and usually provides more options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. token_get_all working great for me.